# How to remove quotes from url address?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am changing the url:

```
history.replaceState('data to be passed', 'Title of the page', '<?php echo getAddress(); ?>/?usp-custom-14="'+urldates+'"&usp-custom-8="'+title+'"');
```

But that gives me:

```
https://example.com/test/results/?usp-custom-14="1934+2017"&usp-custom-8="United%20States"
```

I need to remove the `" "` in order to simply have:

```
https://example.com/test/results/?usp-custom-14=1800+2017&usp-custom-8=United%20States
```

Comment: can't you just remove the `"` from the code?

Comment: `history.replaceState('data to be passed', 'Title of the page', '<?php echo getAddress(); ?>/?usp-custom-14='+urldates+'&usp-custom-8='+title);`

Comment: `"'+urldates+'"` to `'+urldates+'` ?

Comment: no way.. LOL! Need a break

Answer (score 1):

```
istory.replaceState('data to be passed', 'Title of the page', '<?php echo getAddress(); ?>/?usp-custom-14='+urldates+'&usp-custom-8='+title+'');
```

Comment: No need for the `+''` at the end

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
var url = 'https://example.com/test/results/?usp-custom-14="1934+2017"&usp-custom-8="United%20States"'
url = url.replace(/"/g,"");
alert(url) //check the value
```